# How to get Rust compiler to emit BZHI instruction without resorting to platform-specific code?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, llvm, bmi

The Rust compiler & LLVM are sometimes so smart. I used `x = x & (x - 1)` to clear the lowest significant set bit. It recognized this expression and translated it to the `blsr` intrinsic and gave me a big speedup. And without me having to use any platform-specific code or explicitly call out the intrinsic.

I want to get it to do the same thing for the `bzhi` intrinsic, which [zeros high bits starting at a bit index position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI2_(Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_2)). The canonical expression to do this is `src & (1 << inx) - 1` but unfortunately Rust does not recognize it, [emitting five instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/M56erEzMd) instead where one would do. It [knows about the instruction](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._bzhi_u64.html), but doesn't recognize the equivalence.

How could I encourage the Rust compiler to emit the `bzhi` intrinsic without explicitly going to platform-specific code?

Rust 1.66.1, `-C opt-level=3 -C target-cpu=native`

Comment: nit: `target-cpu=native` isn't really helpful since we don't know what cpu you have.

Comment: Hitting the "clear cache + recompile" button got `and sil, 63` / `bzhi`.  (Use `-C overflow-checks` and note that there's integer overflow on the shift with inx=64).  Maybe when you tried, the AWS instance ran on a system where `target-cpu=native` didn't include BMI2?  Or where the tuning settings made it decide not to use it?  (Unwise, it's fast enough even on the AMD CPUs you sometimes get, and `-C target-cpu=znver2` does use BZHI).  Anyway, generally don't use `native` on Godbolt.

Comment: The Wikipedia expression isn't safe in C either; it compiled to BZHI, but relies on undefined behaviour for inx=64.  gcc/clang `-fsanitize=undefined` catch it in a C version.  https://godbolt.org/z/4Tr4qhKvK

Comment: So there's still a non-trivial question here, of how to write something that compiles  *without* the `and` so we can get all 65 different possible results, not the 64 possible results of a 64-bit shift on x86-64.  And which still optimizes to `bzhi`.  Perhaps a special case like `inx>63 ? src :  shift_and`?

Comment: `if(inx>63) { src } else { ... }` hits the missed-optimization you saw, even when the simpler function (that's unsafe for inx=64) compiles to bzhi.  https://godbolt.org/z/3xf4heaWo .  GCC compiles a C++ version of that conditional to a branch + bzhi, so that's not great either.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y5119ejco .  (Even with `unsigned char inx`; BZHI only looks at the low 8 bits of the bit-index operand so compilers have to know that and/or be allowed to assume a smaller value-range. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bzhi)

Comment: I've found two different ways to achieve this, but they each require `unsafe` and an unstable nightly feature, so it's not a satisfying answer. I prefer the `unchecked_shl` version, I suspect the `assume` could cause issues when the function is inlined.
https://rust.godbolt.org/z/6Wh6x97bd

Comment: Nevermind, my `unchecked_shl` version behaves incorrectly at opt-level < 2.